# How can I narrow a union type based on a key, value and a shape provided to a function?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, control-flow, union-types, type-narrowing

I would like to discriminate a union type based on args that provided to a function, but for some reason I can't use a generic type for a shape of data. It brokes my narrowing. What do you think how can I achieve this?

```js
export type DiscriminateUnionType<Map, Tag extends keyof Map, TagValue extends Map[Tag]> = Map extends Record<
  Tag,
  TagValue
>
  ? Map
  : never;

function inStateOfType<Map extends { [index in Tag]: TagValue }, Tag extends keyof Map, TagValue extends Map[Tag], DiscriminatedState extends DiscriminateUnionType<Map, Tag, TagValue>>(tag: Tag, value: TagValue, state: Map): DiscriminatedState | undefined {
  return state[tag] === value ? state as DiscriminatedState : undefined
}

type State = { type: 'loading', a: string } | { type: 'loaded', b: string } | { type: 'someOtherState', c: string }

export function main(state: State) {
  const loadedState = inStateOfType('type', 'loading', state)

  if (loadedState) {
    loadedState.b // Property 'b' does not exist on type 'State'. Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ type: "loading"; a: string; }'
  }
}
```

```js
function inStateOfType<Map extends { type: string }, Tag extends 'type', TagValue extends Map[Tag], DiscriminatedState extends DiscriminateUnionType<Map, Tag, TagValue>>(state: Map, value: TagValue): DiscriminatedState | undefined {
  return state['type'] === value ? state as DiscriminatedState : undefined
}

function main(state: State) {
  // { type: "loaded"; b: string }, everything is fine, narrowing works
  // but in this case, inStateOfType function is not generic
  const loadedState = inStateOfType(state, 'loaded')

  if (loadedState) {
    loadedState.b 
  }
}
```

In order to investigate this I created an executable snippet with a code, so you can debug it on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LdSKWUDwLEzVYMoOM3g+DhvmEAVd0gaQMIoGhpGdbCX1w-CjN0oCKIg8RoNMKSqJogAFNgiEgDwQHwGQ8CgUgiAgXJKCITwXH8TwY1UfAqTwCSoFC8KjFAaLYvixKoGS1LnHSqBMuEfAszoqBGPETgWMYdjqFY7g8Bk0MHCAA)

Comment: You don't want to constrain `Map extends { [index in Tag]: TagValue }` (btw, that `index` is a type parameter name so it should be in uppercase, and also, type parameter names are generally single characters, for better or worse, so I would call this `M extends {[P in K]: V}` or even `M extends Record<K, V>`). That `Map` type is supposed to be the full union, so constraining the value to the type of `value` is going to break things.  I'd widen that and hint to the compiler you want literal types, like [this](//tsplay.dev/WP76Ym). If that works for you I can write up an answer. Let me know.

Comment: Seems, a code you proposed works perfectly fine for me! Thanks!
What do you think is there any possibility to go without type assertion (as any)? @jcalz

Comment: Finally, I got [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-umgdj9?file=index.ts)

Comment: I don't think you can completely avoid a type assertion, although you wouldn't need `as any`.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX73VW).  Of course this sort of thing is usually done with a [user defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJM7W).  I could write up either or both in the answer; let me know.

Comment: I would ask you to keep both. Let's write up the answer :)

Comment: Okay, I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows I am going to change the names of your type parameters to be more in line with TypeScript conventions (single uppercase characters); `Map` will become `M`, `Tag` will become `K` (as it is a **k**ey of `M`), `TagValue` will become `V`, `index` will become `I`, and `DiscriminatedState` will become `S`.  So now we have:

```
function inStateOfType<
  M extends { [I in K]: V },
  K extends keyof M,
  V extends M[K], 
  S extends Extract<M, Record<K, V>>
>(tag: K, value: V, state: M): S | undefined {
  return state[tag] === value ? state as S : undefined
}
```

And note that `{ [I in K]: V }` is equivalent to `Record<K, V>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) and that

```
type DiscriminateUnionType<M, K extends keyof M, V extends M[K]> =
  M extends Record<K, V> ? M : never;
```

can be dispensed with in favor of the built-in [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) as `Extract<M, Record<K, V>>`, so now we have:

```
function inStateOfType<
  M extends Record<K, V>,
  K extends keyof M,
  V extends M[K], S extends Extract<M, Record<K, V>>
>(tag: K, value: V, state: M): S | undefined {
  return state[tag] === value ? state as S : undefined
}
```

We're almost done cleaning this up to the point where we can answer.  One more thing; the `S` type parameter is superfluous. There is no good inference site for it (no parameter is of type `S` or a function of `S`) so the compiler will just fall back to having `S` be exactly `Extract<M, Record<K, V>>`, meaning it's just a synonym for it.

And if you're going to write `return xxx ? yyy as S : undefined` then you don't need to annotate the return type at all, since it will be inferred as `S | undefined`.

So you could write the following and have everything work (or fail to work) the same:

```
function inStateOfType<
  M extends Record<K, V>,
  K extends keyof M,
  V extends M[K]
>(tag: K, value: V, state: M) {
  return state[tag] === value ?
    state as Extract<M, Record<K, V>> :
    undefined
}
```

---

So why doesn't that work?  The big problem here is that `M` is supposed to be the full [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), so you can't [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to `Record<K, V>`, since `V` is just one of the various possible values for the key `K`.  If you constrain `M` to `Record<K, V>`, then the compiler will not let you pass in a value for `state` unless it already knows that its `tag` property is the same type as `value`.  Or, as in your case, the compiler will widen `V` so that it is the full set of possibilities for `tag`.  Oops.

So if we can't constrain `M` to `Record<K, V>`, what *should* we constrain it to?  It needs a key at `K`, but the value type there should only be constrained to be a viable discriminant property.  Something like

```
type DiscriminantValues = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
```

Let's try it:

```
function inStateOfGenericType<
  M extends Record<K, DiscriminantValues>,
  K extends keyof M,
  V extends M[K]
>(tag: K, value: V, state: M) {
  return state[tag] === value ?
    state as Extract<M, Record<K, V>> :
    undefined
}

function main(state: State) {
  const loadedState = inStateOfGenericType('type', 'loaded', state)

  if (loadedState) {
    loadedState.b // okay
  }
}
```

And that does it!

---

Do note that in TypeScript it is a little more conventional to rewrite this as a [user defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) where `inStateOfType()` returns a `boolean` that can be used to decide whether the compiler may narrow `state` to `Record<K, V>` or not:

```
function inStateOfGenericType<
  M extends Record<K, DiscriminantValues>,
  K extends keyof M,
  V extends M[K] 
>(tag: K, value: V, state: M):
  state is Extract<M, Record<K, V>> {
  return state[tag] === value
}

function main(state: State) {
  if (inStateOfGenericType('type', 'loaded', state)) {
    state.b // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJIAuAnjMgMpkhnIC8JpSAPnuVRAFxIByDAHsQAEwCWwAOYCANEhD8oZAE5TpSAL6tSnXN2r8hosRDHykAI2VqN23Ry6UjgqMMgB5MgAsIqugYIS3hbdRkHYkJSUEhYBGRPdWkARjwiRxdkABEJKHh1MCkggFVgCWFgABUeAB4AWQUAaSQIAA9GYDEoJABrCAphADMkRqQANVaOiC6e+oBtJoBdAD4kFmi2Unqpzu6kACUIeGFVMVqmhXG1gH5RpH5gCAA3fwBuDM3SIYBXYHgyBVgEgpIFGJ4hjVqLVHNtdjN9gZ5gBJEHA5b8SZaOSwpAtdp7Hr9QYjRq4yYEhFzRZLBQ0eGzJC5fKFYqMMpAqEQBrNK4rRwrAAU9Gk-EuSGemB+fAmChUQX49QAlPx6Zw-mYhlJzOkvmxVBAyD9VMD5Yx5iKlusmEwJVLkHczcgQD16fwNRAtU8xI4dFEtlkkGDmM4eMYROINJYlEgVOFNFonAYsuHTOZLDZY3YIon9IYZQJ3F5fP5gyEwvY-Y52jBTmQkL9-oDKkgwCApIKnar6IwlbqtqQTsAVEgI2YxMH1mjgxCuYKBFlLCZIzJLE6lZ8ByCRoKx+Zg32CHqtnuJz2IAA6KxIAD0N6QAAVVMJqKpKIIrAIkGJhNAkMBhHrdo8nrFtAwEMsL0fZ9X3fARP2-X8egAoC2hApAwJ4QRkzDJAACIxw0PC3kUCsZBIrQBFxP0thoyJWFiaA4EQJAkgkaQACZdU3NhGwBIFp3PWc6lxHZKUZI4TjOC4+RxY88QZfZiWGUY5K3ClpkZBZljpRSegAUQ6VQEDIHlDmOU5znFa5+T1IURTFBRJQwaVMTlc9FRVIMnA9L0dSPLcDSNE0syCC0QGkK0bVtZzpSQR1z0UV0HiQXztR9PUqz1QNJ1tHDXGXSRVwUGM40rJN81TcR0wUTMypzCqUzcDwIG8PwAnPcss3jei9RrOsGz+fiWzbDsuyDc9D1xIcR1PXLBKCYTqHnRcFEKqN3KCDd-QHCQdzmyb+y3Uc0zPIIr1ve8nxffw4IQn8-xQqZ0Mw6hBEg6CbrfCgPy-B7kMA56R1e5ABHymUCNMIiSNK7NpAoqj5Lo0g6KymJwCYhJWOSABmbidu+Ibm2BUEhMhET5LEzT9kkyyZImFY1IHfFqaJAYVLJeSNMJUYaQFYUIscu0XJlcZNsYTyjq2ILjVNc9wsi60YvteLcVIJ0kqQQy1BMszaek6yVjWXg1dSrpPXS30eNIHLEryyrBEI4rSO68q8yawqausMiE0a3DCxatrS06hRQldnNramWs30GpsBNG4BOw8iatqltgZvrA6ginUnFvJ5aFx4JcndkcWIG23E9qQXdToPNOT1r88LrvT7YJ++C-qQ-9AeA4HgXAj7rrb37EMenu0L7-NsIdyGV2kYiXfq+HtERrdkciFHPh4xj4hYgAxCQ2nxgMsOZAoJCKUBgDIcZ7R6W0l6cYAfjAKx-CcKxhGEDAIBAYFOGfhgDAPlzZ+TEB8Amsdhok2ADOIYABxGY-gJDwC5DCSmelzJSSsgoM+rIr43zvozXELMebKVJEzLY3MqS82WPzByeInL2jcqFCWowpryRliFJ0Csoo2mFnFG4psNYui1kZXWYx9Y4IZsbU2aVvRW0gXxYmrZ2yJ3GnXAKA4M4nWqmdRgOdYFk0QU8dQqCeArSLmtU8a5JqR1IFXGuejNGmyzowZu95hC9BABQaiijWBZQYhjXeyAuTwJ+CAM4x82CBjwRfYo19b4i3vuHTQACX5v1UB-L+P8-5Px+EAkBmp0oQMcMogSudwQIKQWYtBolMFSPpnEy+f9CHJOIfJUhNDyGqXJJg7SSx6GC0YQI0WZdPIm3khrPIYidYAj1hZA2fI1haOloaWWrCIC8KVqM-xepykjTUUnBUKdez123NXSprVqmmJQXOQu1Bi6nVsVtDhx1NkeIwt43xSM9mbyiFoIAA)

Comment: It is a brilliant answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You try to sort of do a reverse discrimination, which really isn't possible. This is because your `TagValue extends Map[Tag]`, where `Tag = type` which unfortunately will always produce a union `'loaded' | 'loading' | 'someOtherValue'`. When you `extend Map[Tag]` it is a sort of narrowing in of itself, so TS does not narrow it further, since `'loaded'` will fulfill the union it'll pass there, but then goes on to pass on the whole union to the `DiscriminatedState`.

So when it tries to use `TagValue` in `DiscriminateUnionType<>`, it'll pass in the entire union and not really narrow it at all.

Instead of having `TagValue extends Map[Tag]` you should instead allow any string, then conditionally check it later. That way your narrowing occurs outside of the generic, where TS might infer and narrow it incorrectly.

```js
function inStateOfGenericTypeFix<
  Map extends Record<string, any>, 
  Tag extends keyof Map, 
  TagValue extends string = Map[Tag], 
> (tag: Tag, value: TagValue, state: Map): 
  TagValue extends Map[Tag] 
  ? DiscriminateUnionType<Map, Tag, typeof value> 
  : unknown
  | undefined 
{
  return state[tag] === value ? state as any : undefined
}

  const loadedState = inStateOfGenericTypeFix('type', 'loaded', state)
  //  ^?

  if (loadedState) {
    loadedState.b //No more error!
  }
```

This unfortunately means you can pass in any string to the `value`, but if the string isn't a valid key, it will return `unknown`, basically letting you know the intended use was wrong. You can also configure this to return undefined or something else as you please.

[Here is a lot of examples/the code on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=59&ssc=37&pln=59&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8qkgLigcgBsB7eAEwEsA7AczwBop5cBnYAJyuqgF8oAfdJnARchEqQil6UAEYt2nHv0FYR+ZkQC2EAPLAAFhDZxEEaQGN5HGjwCwAKAcQAHmCJtgQyFAAi5ZuYcmlSmAKqU5ESUACrCADwAsvBgDNHwXC5IlKTMUADWECBEAGZQSSlQadQAavAEAK7QmRDZueUA2lUAugB8UKjlUM2tUABKEObupHEOUJXpdLPzNXWNDj1LAPxlyUu4lBAAbkYA3A4OxfWU5sCRlFBUJkg6xQDiLUbk5rGQM-Zzg2GOUE7SoEmcD3u3VwVVqDWg3AYSyqQ2cWWBBSKpXKSP+yzhjVR6LayU66S6uLmfgCQRCSFITyaaJawOpgXIwUoYQiUR+EESyVSC3xqwgG3sfQAFAhqDDhYdRXKVvCGKxTLhygBKXBs2lc+mM5RXCTFKiSdBLNgQYD1Nj3NVIdoyrr9ZCoBXwqDbB3QeC5XUcumSQ24Y0QU0HUgObgXK43O6QxkvADCUUC1ogfIFYCJLNyGFUVkUiOWuZGeFU0lhorLwI63QYAc5pgZCCQtf9-nZzaQ4TuWZxyyFysaPR6kp9GsFUA9jSVBIg2t8Xb1LcNAjDEfNaEt1tt9rbEHaFeEeBdbvdNe9h8YnZpgf1wZvoey4bNUfsMcc9ku11uUSgTR4CoCdD1wRlNQtPFJkoVgoGIMgn1MfpE0PFM0ytJA+VA0wGDERCpE1c48XIUpJQQiRW1MSCdzxOYAHp6JUYRcAAIgoyRWJOWQixsEsjiMEADEUfwoC3ABCJY5g4qikAAOhkJYvy-YiXDcDwxLjf97iAqgACYcKQcDDxopZVEwCA4NQJsgz7Xl4kZPDKzwijODwcUGKYqAAD1NiWRioAAdX0RBKhgB5cioYojGsLgDGgTD9wiszhAs1g9JQmzHzsmIHMPJzTxc8Q3OUfDKLwUqNG0PRDGMQ93P8rzfKWGC4Jkw1UEeNC3g+DhvmESUT0gaQyrc1UTMauZmu-OZSKgcjxCQpBTLo+DFtkiAFKU6NiICgAxABJAANABRHw5gACRO0YTocALqgepxXHcTxzKy7l+2EPbyGcbNhw7KBWFi5RKHqTQZCMZRmBAcGiAIYcFz6AZkgB8ZJjYaZkQWLGRwgdYth2MA9igA5jjYM57HMpArOXe8ewgHK+W+37HPwZz8Bkhrv1-eMAK60wXneA4+qZn6-gBFGgVyNGpjiIHOAYeBKBAHpKVLKX8kKEpCbV6tPQ1+WbGRsAyWoLp1nmmUlQYWc1D1xpxvVQmlxxhcAfrckoAJ97ex5XLfkHKoGFUbXbb6YmrjySgiAAd0oJYN1fLdSC9+xaLmRK7UBw8nU9i8ZyvbPkL9RhlagF8TXfHbvzUl7NL-BNdMoABmQy1AgqC5lazx2pvTrKCTHrha+UXnEG9myskaQfSIvEAp8vyZoeMje+ozu5jWgjGS2vFlKAA)

This has been my personal method of doing this sort of type inferencing, and if anyone else has a better method I'd love to hear it.

Comment: `This unfortunately means you can pass in any string to the value, but if the string isn't a valid key, it will return unknown, basically letting you know the intended use was wrong.`


Yeah, that's the thing. Except this downside, what you've proposed looks like a possible and valid solution!

Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: I also would like to recommend you to look at examples made by @jcalz

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575047/how-can-i-narrow-a-union-type-based-on-a-key-value-and-a-shape-provided-to-a-fu/71578899#comment126509695_71575047